# process.env da undefined usando node/express con typescript

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express

**El Problema** : Estoy haciendo un curso en donde se esta utilizando node/express pero con typescript, todo ha sido genial, hasta que comenzamos a usar variables de entorno, y los pasos fueron sencillos, instalar dotenv, luego crear un archivo .env dentro de src, luego importar dotenv.config(), luego usa las variables, y es algo que he hecho multiples veces, pero, siendo primera ves que lo intento en typescript, me da *Undefined*

Dejenme mostarles el código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Chequen que el .env esta dentro de src

**archivo .env**

```
PORT = 5000
NODE_ENV = "development"
JWT_SECRET = "hasdhb66aga36ndghs76sd3"
```

**usando las variables de entorno**

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import { validate, isEmpty } from "class-validator";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import cookie from "cookie";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

import { User } from "../entities/User";

dotenv.config();


const login = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    let errors: any = {};

    if (isEmpty(username)) errors.username = "Username Must Not Be Empty";

    if (isEmpty(password)) errors.password = "Password Must Not Be Empty";

    if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ error: "User Not Found" });

    const passwordMatches = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!passwordMatches) {
      return res.status(401).json({ password: "Password is incorrect" });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ username }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    res.set(
      "Set-Cookie",
      cookie.serialize("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        sameSite: "strict",
        maxAge: 3600,
        path: "/"
      })
    );

    return res.json({ user, token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500);
    console.log(process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  }
};
```

Como podemos observar en el ultimo archivo, quise usar console.log para saber que pasa con el valor de mi variable y ver cual es el error, y el mensaje de consola es el siguiente

```
Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (C:\Users\diego cifuentes\Desktop\Studying  Backend\redit\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:107:20)
    at C:\Users\diego cifuentes\Desktop\Studying  Backend\redit\src\routes\auth.ts:70:23
    at step (C:\Users\diego cifuentes\Desktop\Studying  Backend\redit\src\routes\auth.ts:33:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\diego cifuentes\Desktop\Studying  Backend\redit\src\routes\auth.ts:14:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\diego cifuentes\Desktop\Studying  Backend\redit\src\routes\auth.ts:5:58)
undefined
```

**Objetivo Por Lograr** : En las ultimas tres horas he intentado de todo, de todo literalmente y me sigue dando undefined, no se cual pueda ser el problema realmente, incluso se que es probable que me pidan que intente con require('dotenv').config(), lo cuál no me funciono. Así que, si sabes alguna manera de ayudarme, estaría agradecido, gracias por su tiempo !

Comment: Parece ser que estas ubicando mal el archivo `.env` este debería estar en la raiz del proyecto, no en `src`

Comment: No debería de estar dentro de la carpeta de src ?

Mmm.. que extraño, pense que debería estar ahí.. Aunque, despues de tanto tiempo intentando solucionar aquel problema, probablemente ese sea el error aquí.. Gracias !

Comment: ¿Te funcionó esto?

Comment: Aún no, en un nuevo proyecto lo intentaré, en este decidi hacer un archivo ts con exportando variables para poder terminar el curso, saludos !

Comment: lo que estoy notando es que tu archivo `.env` esta mal ubicado, tiene que estar en la misma carpeta donde tienes el archivo `package.json` y `.gitignore`, otra cosa, estoy viendo que estas leyendo las variables de entorno en un posible archivo controlador, deberías leer las variables al mismo tiempo que inicias el servidor, dentro del `server.ts`

Answer (score 1):

El archivo `.env` esta mal ubicado en tu carpeta `src` no debería de ir, debe de estar en la raíz de tu proyecto, junto al package.

También puedes definir una ruta personalizada si no quieres sacarlo del src, colocas

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import { config } from "dotenv";

config({ path: resolve(__dirname, "./.env") });
```

Si sigue sin funcionar puedes intentar cambiarle el nombre a `.env.local`